# Twitter user stream from server

Tags: twitter, twitter-streaming-api

The twitter user stream [docs](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/userstreams) state

> Note that User Streams are not intended for server-to-server connections.

To maintain some metrics (when the user is away) I need to run a user stream from my server.

I cant user the public stream API as it does not allow me to track more than 400 words.

What happens if I start user stream(s) from my server for, say, a thousand users?

Comment: I think you should go for `site streams`, you can find them below in the same link you've provided.

Comment: @lrnzcig : unfortunately, site streams don't allow me to track specific keywords.

Comment: Well, you can't have everything I guess... I don't know what would happen if you use user streams with 1000 users. I guess you will get an error response similar to the ones for rate limits.

Comment: @lrnzcig : Thanks, guess I'll just have to try and see. I'll leave this open in case any one else has already tried it and would like to enlighten me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is not intended but it is *technically* possible.

Tested with twitter4j on my server.